# Can a Transformer Last until the Heath Death of the Universe if Made with Inorganic Insulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, entropy, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Transformers have no moving parts in direct contact with other solids, do not rely on non-reversible chemical reactions, and do not rely on nuclear reactions. So, with inert materials, the atomic bonds that make up the transformers should theoretically never change after it is manufactured.

As far as I know, commercially produced power transformers age because their insulation between the sets of windings is made of kraft paper (primarily cellulose) and their coolant is made of mineral oil. Both consist of complex organic molecules, which not only are reducing agents strong enough to be used as a fuel in the presence of an oxidizer, but also chemically self-decompose over time. That is further made worse by water ingress into the coolant as the seals (made of rubber) degrade over time. Also, unlike in thermionic/incandescent filaments or integrated circuits, the current density in a transformer winding is low enough that electromigration should be too small to even be measured by electron microscopes.

So, under current design and manufacturing methods, how long can a mass-produced electrical power transformer be realistically made to last at rated load without maintenance? Under the given conditions of

1. that transformer is made entirely of inorganic chemicals that are inert with each other,
2. all atoms that comprise the tranformer are stable isotopes,
3. there are no design or manufacturing defects,
4. the coolant never comes into contact with an oxidizing agent,
5. the transformer is not damaged or destroyed, and
6. the power supply stops outputting power when the last brown dwarf becomes a black dwarf,
   will the transformer last at full-load rating until the Heat Death of the Universe?

Comment: Ive looked at the wording on this question for a while, and I'm having trouble with the phrase "mass-produced electrical power transformer."  The mass produced transformers are produced to be economical, not to be eternal.  You'd never "mass produce" something eternal.  That phrasing feels at odds with everything else you're thinking about... especially when you start talking about heat death of the universe.

Comment: By mass-produced, I'm meaning capable of being mass produced using current technology, even if it will bankrupt the manufacturer because no one will ever need to buy one again. Of course, no transformer that is currently actually mass produced can last that long.

Comment: "So, with inert materials, the atomic bonds that make up the transformers should theoretically never change after it is manufactured."  Not strictly true;  pretty much anything will eventually sublimate if you wait long enough.

Comment: Electromigration?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a theoretical question, hence a physics question, and not at all an engineering question about practical transformer design or construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transformer will last nowhere near the heat death of the universe.  The heat death of the universe is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long time away.  And to be perfectly fair, I should have had far more "really"s there, but you'd have to scroll past them and that wouldn't be nice.  As a [lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe#Current_status), the heat death of the universe is *at least* $10^{106}$ years away, because it would take that long for some of the largest black holes to evaporate.  Let's give that number credit and spell it out.  That's 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years.  This is long enough that your intuition about what matters starts to fall short.  You mention that the coolant doesn't come in contact with an oxidizing agent, thinking that will matter on this timescale.  In reality, we worry about things like [proton decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay).  Modern science literally doesn't know whether protons themselves decay.  The best we know is that the half life is at least $1.67\cdot10^{34}$ years, but that's an astonishingly short time compared to the heat death of the universe.  It's within the error bounds of the best of modern science that the half life of a proton is $10^{35}$ years, in which case nearly all of the protons in your material will have decayed before the heat death of the universe.  And by "nearly all," I mean you have $10^71$ half-lives of your proton, so each proton has only a $\frac{1}{2}^{10^{71}}$ chance of surviving.  I'd write out how many zeroes appear at the start of that percentage, but I'd run out of space in the stack exchange answer size limit.

So let's walk back from the heat death of the universe.  That's so far out that talk of "insulators" is ... quaint.

We also have to consider externalizes.  On the order of 7 billion years from now, [the sun will expand](https://spaceandbeyondbox.com/life-cycle-of-the-sun/) as it burns up its primary fuel.  It may even engulf the Earth, in which case all talk of "not contacting oxidizers" is rendered moot by fusion-hot plasma melting everything.

So what can we do?  Well, the best measure I can think of for what you're interested in is the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) of a compound.  This is a very useful measure for how stable a compound is.  The Gibbs free energy of [Aluminum trioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation) ($Al_2O_3$) at standard temperature and pressure (which your question vaguely suggests is the right temperature and pressure to use) is −1582.3 kJ/mol.  So it is the compound least likely to decompose over time.  It is also an insulator and can be produced with modern manufacturing means.

How long does it last?  That gets into a funny question.  Like all compounds, it exists in a balance with its decomposed elements.  Having a very low (very negative) Gibbs free energy, it is a very favored form.  I've seen aluminum oxide's lifespan listed as "indefinite."  But in reality, it's not.

The hard question is what happens after it decomposes.  If the oxygen hangs around, it is very likely to re-combine with the aluminum, and thus not really decompose meaningfully.  But if the oxygen escapes, then the insulator slowly turns into aluminum.  How fast this happens depends on your seals, which are not well specified.  On the short term, the insulation is perfect.  But on the scale of millions of years, we have to consider such things